# Prolema com layout do R Studio

Tags: r

Acabei de instalar o R Studio e ele não está igual eu vejo em todos os tutoriais na internet com quatro janelas. Ao invés disso está assim:

[image: R Studio]

Alguém sabe como arrumar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este não é o RStudio. Este é o R puro, sem IDE. Baixe o RStudio Desktop [neste link](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download3/) e seja feliz.

Comment: Obrigada! Agora funcionou.